# Adding in-memory state to a web API with genservers

Tags: elixir, pid, gen-server

I'm currently trying to build a small web API in Elixir which needs some in-memory state. In a nutshell, the first time a user uses the API he starts a certain business process which he can later continue with further API calls.

For this, I've seen that the best approach is to create a GenServer, store the state there and then have further API calls work with it through the PID.

While trying to search how to `stringify` the PID in order to return it in each API call I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/ADaRIYJBbEg) which said:

> PIDs aren't guaranteed to be unique as they get recycled.

So my question is: what would be the best approach for this scenario? How is it typically solved?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but you can use the [Registry](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html) to register and lookup a Process with a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[:erlang.make_ref()](https://erldocs.com/21.0/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=make_ref#make_ref/0) can be used to create a unique identifier:

```
iex(1)> :erlang.make_ref()
#Reference<0.3918424786.2664955905.32640>

iex(2)>
```

(Is there a reason you don't want to use [System.unique_integer/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#unique_integer/1) ?)

The Elixir docs [mention](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html) the `Reference`, `Pid`, `Port` data types, but I can't find any info on the `Reference` type in Elixir, e.g. whether Elixir has a native function which creates references.

**Response to comment**:

Here's how you can convert a reference to a string* in Elixir:

```
iex(4)> make_ref() |> inspect()  
"#Reference<0.784388646.1821114370.207624>"
```

*Credit to Hauleth in the comments for finding `Kernel.make_ref()`.

> would that work?

According to the [Kernel docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#make_ref/0):

> The returned reference will re-occur after approximately 2^82 calls;
>   therefore it is unique enough for practical purposes.

Comment: I'm just new to Elixir/OTP, that's all. Since I need to pass those identifiers around back and forth the API as strings, would that work? After reading up, I think registering `System.unique_integer/1` as the genserver's name might be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: *I think registering System.unique_integer/1 as the genserver's name* -- Huh?  Don't do that.  Why do you need to convert a Ref to a string in the first place?

Comment: @7stud maybe I'm not understanding properly how to use Genservers. My intention is to start a different one for each API connection, so each API user can access the data via its unique reference. I can't give them names since eventually there would be collisions – that's why the reference stuff.

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano,  Okay, so you are going to use the *return value* of `System.unique_integer` as the server name.  That's fine.